# java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access on 32 bit Windows

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I have JNA wrapper for a C DLL. It works fine, except when used on a Windows 32-bit system. Here is a simplified example:

```
int SetData(const wchar_t* data);

int SetId(const wchar_t* id, uint32_t flags);
```

I created JNA bindings as follows:

```
public static native int SetData(WString data);

public static native int SetId(WString id, int flags);
```

The first function SetData() works fine on both 32-bit as well as 64-bit Windows, but the second function crashes on Windows 7 32-bit.

I tried using NativeLong as suggested in other related posts, but it didn't help.

Here is the link to the repository:

https://github.com/cryptlex/lexactivator-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cryptlex/lexactivator/LexActivatorNative.java

Comment: Have you tried the mapping with out the `native` keyword?  In Java that implies a JNI solution which in JNA translates to the "direct mapping" implementation. Direct mapping has some limitations with regard to wrapper classes and type mappers, and it might be possible that `WString` doesn't play nice with direct mapping without a custom type mapper.

Comment: @DanielWiddis The first function also uses wstring and works fine. I guess the problem is with int.

Comment: `int` is the correct mapping for a 32-bit integer.  It's entirely possible the error is not in the mapping, and is just a symptom.  Can you show the code where you actually call that method?  What memory is it attempting to "set"?

Comment: Is the name mismatch just a typo?

Comment: @DanielWiddis Here is the actual call: https://github.com/cryptlex/lexactivator-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cryptlex/lexactivator/LexActivator.java#L72

Comment: c library has separate build for 32 bit?

Comment: @vish Yes, 32 bit has a separate build.

Comment: @adnankamili c code is proprietary, which is expected. But without that, I am not sure how we can proceed, not to mention I have not had 32 OS for at least 10 years. Perhaps you can prepare a simple sample? For now, the only thing I can think of is C has ` uint32_t` for flags while java has `int`. That should not cause problems though. Make sure 32 bit build is `unicode` since you are using WString. And of course you need to check for stack corruption because of different builds.

Comment: @adnankamili How are you actually calling that method?  Is it associated with a callback?

Comment: @DanielWiddis The code crashes when we call MyLib.SetId("abc", 1); There is no callback.

Comment: @adnankamili You still haven't given any context around the call.  The problem is not the mapping. It's something else in your program. You are calling a static method so there's no indication of what it's operating on.  The string is being written to some memory somewhere. The [docs](https://docs.cryptlex.com/node-locked-licenses/using-lexactivator/using-lexactivator-with-c-c++-and-objective-c) say you need to link the `x64` or `x86` version of the DLL appropriately.  Have you done that? (I don't see it in your code, just one `Native.load()` call of the same lib name.)

Comment: @DanielWiddis JNA handles that, we just need to place the libraries in specific folders. Also, the docs for Java are different

Comment: @DanielWiddis Here is a sample that crashes on Windows 32 bit (if it helps): https://github.com/cryptlex/lexactivator-java/tree/master/examples/sample

Comment: @adnankamili 1. The mappings with `WString` and `int` are correct. For troubleshooting you can experiment with a `char[]` argument instead of `WString`, either is equivalent in this case.  2. The problem is either with a dependency (wrong dll bitness, wrong VS2015 bitness, etc.) or with the C code/native implementation of `SetId()`.  Assuming you have access to this C code, investigate what memory the ID is being written to and why you do not have access to that memory.   Make sure the platform is expecting unicode strings.  See if strings need null terminators.

Comment: @adnankamili FYI, I just used a Windows 7 32-bit VM, cloned the project via git, installed the dll's using the shell command (no instructions in the documentation, btw), installed VS2015 (x86 version) and executed the sample project.   No crash, got "42: Invalid product data." which I assume is expected, not having a valid data key.  Commented that line out to get to the problematic one, "43: The product id is incorrect."  Still no crash. So I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DanielWiddis thanks for checking this, but it is still replicable.  You only had to run the sample project, dlls are already inside the jar file.

Comment: It may be replicable for you but not for me. Meaning the problem is not in the code you've quoted in your question, but some other configuration that differs.  At least this narrows down your problem to the differences between your setup and mine.  Is it the location of the DLLs in the jar vs. filesystem that's the problem?  Do you have the same x86 version of VS2015 installed?

Comment: Try using the following data https://pastebin.com/BfbFNATh in the following sample: https://github.com/cryptlex/lexactivator-java/tree/master/examples/sample You don't need to download any libs. POM file contains the library reference.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Try opening the sample folder (not the root repo folder) in NetBeans (for example) and it crashes when run. SetProductId() function crashes but the SetProductData() function succeeds, which implies proper libs are loaded.

Comment: I was executing the sample properly. The issue was that I needed a valid Product ID which you helpfully provided.  I've written an answer summarizing everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mappings are correct:  `WString` is the correct mapping for `const wchar_t*`, and `int` (always 32 bits in Java) is the correct mapping for `uint32_t` (always 32 bits), with a caveat about signededness that shouldn't matter when used as a flags bitmask.

I'm not sure where you read that `NativeLong` would be appropriate here.  This is primarily intended for *nix native code in which `sizeof(long)` differs based on the OS bitness.  Practically, it doesn't actually matter on Windows since `LONG` is always 32-bit, but it involves unnecessary object creation vs. a primitive.

The "Invalid Memory Access" error thrown by JNA is a "graceful" handling of native memory errors caught by [Structured Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160). All you really need to know is that either **You are attempting to access native memory that you do not own** or **Your native memory allocation failed**.

Debugging these errors always involves carefully tracking memory allocations. When is memory allocated?  When is it released?  Who (Java-side or native side) is responsible for this allocation?  Your program is likely crashing at the point you attempt to copy data from the user-provided ID string to some native memory that your native DLL is accessing.  So that points to two memory pointers you need to investigate.

- Look at the memory where the ID string is being written.  Find out when the memory for it is allocated. Ensure it is large enough for the string (should be 2x string length + 2 bytes for a null terminator) and properly zeroed (or a null byte explicitly appended).  Verify all WinAPI calls use the correct (W vs. A) unicode version.

  - I tried adding `LA_IN_MEMORY` to the `flags` bitmask and got an error message "Either trial has not started or has been tampered! Trial days left: 30".  This is apparently produced by the next line (`IsLicenseGenuine()`), meaning that the `setProductId()` call was successful.
  - Identifying what your native code does differently when the `LA_IN_MEMORY` flag is not set will probably be very helpful.  It's possible the invalid memory access is associated with identifying the directory or file to be used.

    - There is a recent changelog entry for 3.14.9 involving this flag. Looking at that commit might give a hint to the problem.
    - There's another recent change in 3.15.0 involving auto-detection of a file on Windows which also may be suspicious given that `LA_IN_MEMORY` makes the problem go away.
  - When given an invalid key, the error message "43: The product id is incorrect." is returned, so the point in native code where unowned memory is being accessed is after this error check.
- Trace what is happening with the ID string defined on the Java side.  Given the constant definition of the string, the actual memory allocation is likely not a problem, but keep track of the native pointer to this string to be sure it's not inadvertently overwritten.

As you've noted in the comments, reducing the native memory allocation solves this issue, indicating you are hitting a limit.  It turns out the default 32-bit Java native memory allocation for stack size (`-Xss`) is 320 KB.  From [Oracle docs](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/hotspotfaq.html#threads_oom):

> On Windows, the default thread stack size is read from the binary
> (java.exe). As of Java SE 6, this value is 320k in the 32-bit VM and
> 1024k in the 64-bit VM.
>
> You can reduce your stack size by running with the -Xss option. For
> example:
>
> java -server -Xss64k
>
> Note that on some versions of Windows, the OS may round up thread
> stack sizes using very coarse granularity. If the requested size is
> less than the default size by 1K or more, the stack size is rounded up
> to the default; otherwise, the stack size is rounded up to a multiple
> of 1 MB.

You could increase this limit to solve the problem or, as you've indicated in the remarks, lower your native allocation.  You might wish to be more conservative than 300K as that only leaves a small amount for other use of the stack.  You might also start smaller, check the return value for `ERR_MORE_DATA` and try again with a larger value.  300KB seems a rather huge amount to devote to registry values.

Note also that 32-bit Java has a [total process memory size limit of either 2GB or 4GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630790/java-out-of-memory-errornative-memory-the-process-size-limit-was-hit32-bit-l), depending on the OS.  If your Java heap allocation grows close to that limit, it reduces the native amount available to you.  You can control how big the heap gets with the `-Xmx` switch and you can also ensure sufficient native memory allocation with the `-Xss` switch.  Use these switches in a combination to avoid hitting the process size limit.

Comment: One more observation, the functions in the dll which are reading from Windows registry are causing the crash - RegQueryValueEx. It happens when dll is invoked from Java, otherwise dlls work fine in C/C++ on 32 bit. The buffer size when reading from Windows registry is set to 404800, can this be concern, like java not allowing such a big char array inside a DLL?

Comment: It turned out the be the array size, using a char array of size more than 300KB causes this error. So for 32 bit I set the max array size to 307200 and it worked fine.

Comment: @adnankamili glad you solved it.  I wonder if the `-Xss` switch in Java has an impact?  BTW, you don't need to choose an array size in advance, you can try one and check the return value for ERR_MORE_DATA and try again.

Comment: @adnankamili Looks like 32-bit Java has a total process size limit of either 4GB or 2GB, depending on OS.   If you let Java have larger heap (close to that limit) that lowers the native OS amount available, which could be the error here.    You might try reducing the Java heap allocation to increase the native memory available.  I suspect explicitly specifying `-Xmx`/`Xms` and `-Xss` switches on Windows 32 bit, or clearly documenting this requirement for users.

Comment: @adnankamili Aha, the default `-Xss` is 320 KB.   So your fix will work in the "default" case.  Fun.

Comment: Thanks for the info, now I exactly know why 320 KB.